# Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in php mvc

Tags: php

I have main index.php file where i call other controllers and that is fine.

I call them with `call_user_func_array([$object, $this->method], $this->params);`

For example i first include controller and then i call it. My controller is called IndexController and this is example how i include it and call it.

IndexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        print 'welcome to oxbir'."<BR>";
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->view('panel/user');
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

class Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function view($view)
    {
        include('views/'.$view.'.php');
    }
}
```

but I see this error...

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\php\controllers\IndexController.php on line 3

Comment: You have to `include` or `require` the files where the required class is defined. So you `indexController.php` needs `require("Controller.php");` at the begin.

Comment: I changed it, but I did not solve my problem

Comment: So please edit your question to reflect the changes you made.

Comment: I changed my post, you can see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Controller {
```

To

```
<?php
require_once('Controller.php');

class IndexController extends Controller {
```

You need to include the controller file or use some kind of autoload.

Comment: So your Controller.php is not in the same folder?

Comment: All you have to do is to include the file. If it is in a different folder, set the relative or absolute path to the file, like `'./Controller.php'`, or `__DIR__.'/../Controller.php'`