# PHP debugging with Xdebug

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have a PHP project using XAMPP. And I try to debug with Xdebug plugin in Visual Studio Code.

The project about is a MVC framework. And on top of this framework I build a application.

So I have a folder `controllers`. And I have a folder `Libraries` within it the base controller.

But when I start Xdebug. I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Controller" not found in E:\Xampp\htdocs\shareposts\app\controllers\Users.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown
```

So I googled for this error and I found this: [Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in php mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909391/fatal-error-class-controller-not-found-in-php-mvc)

But that doesn't worked. And I can't of course put the `Controller.php` in the same folder as `Users.php`.

So this is the Users.php controller file:

```
<?php

require_once('Controller.php');
class Users extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->userModel = $this->model('User');
  }  
}
?>
```

**So my question is:** what I have to change?

So this is the controller class:

```
<?php
  /*
   * Base Controller
   * Loads the models and views
   */
  class Controller {
    // Load model
    public function model($model){
      // Require model file
      require_once '../app/models/' . $model . '.php';

      // Instatiate model
      return new $model();
    }

    // Load view
    public function view($view, $data = []){
      // Check for view file
      if(file_exists('../app/views/' . $view . '.php')){
        require_once '../app/views/' . $view . '.php';
      } else {
        // View does not exist
        die('View does not exist');
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the bootstrap class. For initialising the files, when the project is starts:

```
<?php
  // Load Config
  require_once 'config/config.php';
  // Load Helpers
  require_once 'helpers/url_helper.php';
  require_once 'helpers/session_helper.php';

  // Autoload Core Libraries
  spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    require_once 'libraries/' . $className . '.php';
  });
```

and this is the launch.json file:

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 0,
      "runtimeArgs": ["-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"],
      "env": {
        "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
        "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
        "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
        "-S",
        "localhost:0"
      ],
      "program": "",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "port": 9003,
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:8080([0-9]+)\\) started",
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:8080%s",
        "action": "openExternally"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

for example if I do this:

```
<?php

function test()
{
  $var = 1;
  $var++;
  return $var;
}

$hello = test();
echo $hello;
```

in a seperated project.

Then it works - I can debug the code.

Comment: I think we need to know more about `Controller.php` and if you're using name spacing, and if you're simply using `class Controller { }` within that file?

Comment: https://www.thoughtfulcode.com/a-complete-guide-to-php-namespaces/

Comment: Is this solely a problem when XDebug is enabled?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? I made a litte test project with just index.php in it. And then it works with xdebug.

Comment: Does the original code run properly when XDebug is not enabled?

Comment: yes of course. I just can start the application

Comment: It sounds to me that you are trying to debug your `Users.php` file **directly** and therefore bypassing the whole framework bootstrap logic (that's why PHP is unable to locate your base `Controller` class since the class autoloading code was not loaded). **You should debug the URL instead** -- so that the request goes through the whole framework including bootstrap code and then hits the breakpoint in your `Users` controller class.

Comment: oke, but how to do that then? Because this is the link: http://localhost:8080/shareposts/users/login

Comment: Of course I refresh the browser page and that it has to hit the breakpoint in the code. I don' understand what you mean

Comment: https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug#vs-code-configuration . You need to use your `Listen for Xdebug` config and have `debug.start_with_request=yes` or pass the Xdebug cookie with the request (e.g. using Xdebug browser extension).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I wich file I have to edit something?

Comment: Great :) Consider making an answer with the final config/steps taken -- this will help others in a similar situation. A Question with accepted Answer is much more visible & valuable than finding a solution deep in the comments.